# can someone explain what is this non-clickable permanent window called @!0,35;BDHF always open on wayland?

Tags: gnome, wayland, pop-os, display-manager

Pop!_OS 21.10, amdgpu, ryzen 5 4500u, issue only on Wayland. 
Linux 5.15.5-76051505-generic

snap attached [image]below (i couldn't even screenshot that thing).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It looks like a known gnome-extension bug **[1]**.
The extension at issue is *DING* **[2]**.

You can workaround the issue by disabling it with: `gnome-extensions disable ding@rastersoft.com`

---

**[1]** https://github.com/pop-os/shell/issues/1075
**[2]** https://gitlab.com/rastersoft/desktop-icons-ng

Comment: thanks man. i would be grateful if you aware of any workaround to keep desktop icons with this bug gone.

Comment: @karthiknair sorry, I do not use desktop icons anymore...

Comment: oh okay..... thats fine